# Reporting Services behind Amazon ELB

Tags: reporting-services, amazon-elb

I want to run SQL Reporting Services behind an amazon load balancer.

The problem is that I can't redirect traffic from the load balancer to the

```
http://server/reportserver
```

url. Just to  a specific port.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this ?

Thanks.